# Access Google Maps API json in browser

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-api

Silly question I am sure.

But how can I access this for simple testing but also whilst inside a `phonegap` which has no `URL` directly through the browser:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=122+flinders+st,+darlinghurst,+nsw,+australia&sensor=false&key=API_KEY
```

I have of course changed the API key which is a browser key. I have also changed my `Referers:  *` So everything should be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try [**this**](http://tomschott.com/blog/articles/phonegap-google-maps-example). It's a very simple phonegap maps api example.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the Advanced REST Client Plugin which is free and you can install it on your chrome browser. This plugin opens directly in browser tab and you can set the request in a huge text box, set the type of request (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE etc) and also the parameters if required. You can see the results in below when you hit submit.

This Plugin is exclusively made for testing purposes relating to matter like sending a request to an API and then getting the results back from it in either JSON or XML format.

Click this [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US) in order to install it in your Chrome Browser.

Hope that Helps!!